# Cache from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, caching

i have a Cache in C++ and i was wondering how could i do the same implementation in Java, im trying to do some implementation for this, but i don't even know if the Class Cache in Java can be use for the same thing, as well as i don't know how to initialize this Cache, in C++ they just use it without setting a value

```
Cache cache;
double score = player_move(player_grid, cache, depth - 1);
```

--------------Then inside the player_move method it uses the cache like this-------------

```
    Cache::const_iterator iter = cache.find(computer_grid);
    if (iter != cache.end())
    {
        computer_score = iter->second;
    }
    else
    {
        computer_score = computer_move(computer_grid, depth - 1);
        cache[computer_grid] = computer_score;
    }
```

Comment: What, on earth, is "a cache in c++"?

Comment: It looks like something that can be implemented with a HashMap (assuming that this Cache class maps `computer_grid`s (whatever those are) to `computer_score`s).

Comment: don't really know, i was trying to implement this code in Java, and suddenly this shows up, and i can't figure it out yet

Comment: @FrancoFerrari If you can't figure out what it even is... how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Found this 

typedef std::unordered_map<Grid, double, std::hash<Grid> > Cache;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the information from your latest comment

```
typedef std::unordered_map<Grid, double, std::hash<Grid> > Cache
```

we can see that a "Cache" in your program is simply an "unordered_map". The Java equivalent to this is a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Note that you may have to override the methods "hashCode" and "equals" in your class "Grid".

However, usually there is more to a cache than the map itself. You usually need some mechanism to control the memory used by your cache, in order to avoid the cache holding on to every possible result forever. Otherwise, iff the number of possible inputs isn't bound, your program will run out of memory sooner or later.

Comment: thanks, would you define this new hashmap as
`Map<double, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: You want Grid -> Double (like in C++), not Double -> Object. Therefore: Map<Grid, Double> cache = new HashMap<Grid, Double>();

Comment: It lets me do it like this, im working on it right now, but this is fix at least, im trying to do the implementation now `Map<Grid, Double> cache = new HashMap<>();`